# how can i separate from this list?

Tags: python, list, arraylist

```
text = [('good', 'Title meta tag contains no errors.'), ('good', 'Title relevancy to page content is good.'), ('good', 'Description meta tag contains no errors.'), ('good', 'Description relevancy to page content is excellent.'), ('good', 'Keywords meta tag contains no errors.'), ('good', 'Keyword relevancy to page content is excellent.'), ('good', 'The Robots meta tag contains no errors.'), ('good', 'The Author meta tag contains no errors.'), ('good', 'The size of the web page.'), ('good', 'The web page load time.')]
```

the question is how can i separate the list to

```
text = ['good', 'Title meta tag contains no errors.', 'good', 'Title relevancy to page content is good.', 'good', 'Description meta tag contains no errors.', 'good', 'Description relevancy to page content is excellent.', 'good', 'Keywords meta tag contains no errors.', 'good', 'Keyword relevancy to page content is excellent.', 'good', 'The Robots meta tag contains no errors.', 'good', 'The Author meta tag contains no errors.', 'good', 'The size of the web page.', 'good', 'The web page load time.']
```

any answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
result = [y for x in text for y in x]
```

Another alternative that you may find more readable is to use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain(*text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question, very nice solution:

- [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Something like this should work:

```
>>> a=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> [i for sl in a for i in sl]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: :) Thank you! But do take a look at the link - very nice, several solutions and a good explanation given there.